# Corollary of Projection Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

I am having difficulty proving the following:

If $M$ is a closed, proper, subspace of a Hilbert space $\mathfrak{H}$, then there exists a non-zero vector $y$ in $\mathfrak{H}$ with $y \perp M$.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Start with a $z \notin M$. Apply the projection theorem.

Comment: The proof of this result can be found in the book of Luenberger: "Optimization by Vector Space Methods" 1969. See section 3.3 "The Projection Theorem" where a nice proof is detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Take any $x \in \mathfrak{H}$ such that $x$ is not in $M$. Then by the projection theorem, there exists an $z$ in $M$ such that $||x-y||$ is minimum. Show that $(x-y) \perp M$.